# How can I modify this blog loop to display custom post type posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Here's my code to generate a two columm blog index page. I want to modify it so that I can use it as an index page for my portfolio custom post type- query_posts('post_type=portfolio').

I know that I need to modify the first quater of the code, but I just don't know what to change. Can you please help me?

Code:

```
 <?php
/*
Template Name: 2 Column Blog Template
*/
get_header();
?>
<section class="container">
<!-- 960 Container -->
    <?php
    $counter = 1; //start counter
    $grids = 2; //Grids per row
    global $query_string; //Need this to make pagination work
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
             $offset = 0;
                if ($paged != 0 ) {
                    $offset = ($paged-1) * get_query_var('posts_per_page') ;
                }
                query_posts('offset=' . $offset);
                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
global $more;
$more = 0;
?>
<?php
//Show the first post
if($counter == 1) :
?>
    <article class="eight columns" id="entry-<?php the_ID(); ?>"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </a>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a></h2>
        <p class="blog_meta">
            By <em><?php the_author() ?></em> on:<?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
        </p>
        <p class="blog_preview">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </p>
    </article>
<?php
//Show the last post
elseif($counter == $grids) :
?>
    <article class="eight columns" id="entry-<?php the_ID(); ?>"> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </a>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a></h2>
        <p class="blog_meta">
            By <em><?php the_author() ?></em> on:<?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?>
        </p>
        <p class="blog_preview">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </p>
    </article>
    <hr class="clear"><?php $counter = 0; endif;?><?php $counter++; endwhile; //sets a clear:both and resets counter for next row of posts ?>
    <nav id="pagination">
        <hr class="pagination_margin">
        <div id="pagination_previous">
            <?php previous_posts_link('Previous'); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="pagination_next">
            <?php next_posts_link('Next'); ?>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</section>
<?php
get_footer();
?>
```

Comment: Use query_posts('post_type=portfolio&offset=' . $offset);

Comment: I did it. Check below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code to use the correct query_posts call. Use

```
query_posts('post_type=portfolio&offset=' . $offset);
```

instead of

```
query_posts('offset=' . $offset);
```

Below is your code modified:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: 2 Column Blog Template
*/
get_header();
?>
<section class="container">
<!-- 960 Container -->
    <?php
    $counter = 1; //start counter
    $grids = 2; //Grids per row
    global $query_string; //Need this to make pagination work
    $paged = get_query_var('paged');
             $offset = 0;
                if ($paged != 0 ) {
                    $offset = ($paged-1) * get_query_var('posts_per_page') ;
                }
                query_posts('offset=' . $offset);
                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
global $more;
$more = 0;
...
```

The complete codex manual for query_posts is [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)